# Facebook: stay in canvas after oauth callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-canvas

I'm working on an app using facebook & oauth. The app lives inside a facebook canvas, and the authentication is done server side. The app is done w/ Ruby on Rails 3.2, using Koala for dealing with the api (and mongodb as backend, for what it's worth), and hosted on heroku.

So, I supply the heroku url as redirect_url for the callback. Which makes the user go out of the canvas after the authentication, and well, I want it to stay inside. I read a few threads about this that suggested I redirect to the canvas url with js once the authentication is done. I did that, but now it seems that my session token is never set, and the user goes through the auth flow every time he tries to see a non-public page (which means he loops on the welcome page, having an "invisible" exchange with facebook each time).

I don't really get what I'm doing wrong here, so any help is welcome. If you need more informations, just ask.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: How are you setting your session token?  Also, are you passing the access token back during the redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what was my problem : the page my canvas pointed to was a "public" page, and did not handle anything authentication related, meaning it didn't parse the `signed_request`, or anything else. I ended up setting a special endpoint for the canvas in charge of handling the `signed_request` logic, and now it works as one would expect.